# Failed in SublimeClang for lackness of LibClang

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang

I had already had sublime and when setting up new plug-ins, I found problem for the setup of SublimeClang. It requires libClang but I searched all my folders using the " locate clang" command and couln't find libclang at last (The doc on the web said it should be located in usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/).

When i open the sublime, the console printed out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/meng/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeClang/internals/clang/cindex.py", line 95, in get_cindex_library
return cdll.LoadLibrary(filename) 
File "./ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
File "./ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
OSError: libclang.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
error: It looks like libclang.so couldn't be loaded. You have to compile it yourself, or download from https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang/downloads.

Please note that this plugin uses features from clang 3.0 so make sure that is the version you have installed.

Once you have the file, you need to copy libclang.so into the root of this plugin. See http://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang for more details.
```

I'm rookie in ubuntu OS and hope someone can give me help. Many thanks!